# Read file to linked list in C programming

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm new to programming in C. I came to the chapter of linked lists and I can't move on from this task at all. Can you please show me how to create a linked list according to the instructions provided?

I need to load text from a text file into a linked list.

*Thanks for help.*

---

Pattern for text file looks like this:

```
room number
number of beds (the number of beds determines how many guests will be accommodated in the room and how many guests will be loaded in the linked list)
the price
#
guest name
address
#
guest name
address
---
etc.
```

The text file looks like this:

```
514
2
12,5
#
John Smith
Street 25, New York
#
Kate Smith
Streer 25, New York
---
134
1
20
#
Michael Collins
Street 12, Nebraska
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you know how to read a text file into, say, a list of strings?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting. If you're unable to get started, I'd suggest you review the materials in the chapters leading up to this one again.

Comment: Do you need to create a set of linked lists, one for each room. Or one linked list, with each node having info about people in it. Or a linked list of rooms, with each room as a separate linked list?

Comment: @John - What's `12,5` - one price, or two prices?